# dealing with non-custom components in DOTS

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to start learning Unity DOTS with a simple 2D movement. I took the currently newest video to dive into it

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BNMrevfB6Q0

and know how to setup a custom component with a system. But for the movement I need the `Rigidbody2D` component now so I attached it to my gameobject.

[image]

My conversion script converts that GO to an entity

```
public class MovementBehaviour : MonoBehaviour, IConvertGameObjectToEntity
{
    [SerializeField]
    private float movementSpeed;

    public void Convert(Entity entity, EntityManager dstManager, GameObjectConversionSystem conversionSystem)
    {
        dstManager.AddComponentData(entity, new MovementInputComponent());
        dstManager.AddComponentData(entity, new MovementSpeedComponent { Value = movementSpeed });
        // rigidbody gets converted automatically ... ?
    }
}
```

And the system should handle a simple physics movement

```
public class MovementSystem : JobComponentSystem
{
    [BurstCompile]
    struct MovementJob : IJobForEach<MovementInputComponent, MovementSpeedComponent, Rigidbody2D>
    {
        public float fixedDeltaTime;

        public void Execute(ref MovementInputComponent movementInput, ref MovementSpeedComponent movementSpeed, ref Rigidbody2D rigidbody)
        {
            // rb.MovePosition(rb.position + movementInput + movementSpeed * fixedDeltaTime);
        }
    }

    protected override JobHandle OnUpdate(JobHandle inputDeps)
    {
        MovementJob job = new MovementJob { fixedDeltaTime = Time.fixedDeltaTime };
        return job.Schedule(this, inputDeps);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the `MovementJob` throws an error

> The type 'Rigidbody2D' must be a non-nullable value type in order to
>   use it as parameter 'T2' in the generic type or method
>   'IJobForEach'

so does someone know how to deal with the Rigidbody component?

Comment: AFAIK Unity doesn't have full support for all physics components in jobs yet (last I checked it's still in progress), so you might have to roll something of your own (in the latest Unity version you get access to some parts of the physics system, such as raycasts and navmesh queries, which might be sufficient, depending on what exactly you are trying to achieve)

Comment: thanks. so it seems I have to write my own physics logic .. ?

Comment: At least until Unity finishes work on jobyfying the entire physics system. There are some posts on the Unity forums with samples that might be useful: https://forum.unity.com/threads/100-000-entities-traversing-navmesh.534526/